# Copy data from one column to another column from a specific row in R dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I have a dataframe (dimensions = 1134*14) and would like to copy part of the data values from one column to another column in the same dataframe in R for further reshaping the data for plotting purpose. I would like to copy the data values from row 371 to row 1134 from(**Aggregate to Cluster column**, and another from  **sub_aggregate to cluster_location** column)

Please assist me how to copy data from a specific row.

Thank you,

Toufiq

Example of the input and expected output data are provided below:

> Input

```
dput(df_1)
structure(list(position = c("A28.1", "A34.1", "A38.2", "A1.19", 
"A37.10", "A37.2", "A37.11", "A1.32", "A35.6", "A8.35", "A8.36", 
"A8.37", "A8.38", "A8.39", "A8.40", "A8.41", "A8.42", "A8.9"), 
    Set = c("M10.1", "M10.3", "M10.4", "M11.1", "M11.2", "M11.3", 
    "M11.4", "M12.1", "M12.10", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    ""), Group_A = c(95.23809524, -63.15789474, 33.33333333, 
    0, -23.33333333, -26.31578947, -20.83333333, 17.39130435, 
    -67.34693878, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Group_B = c(0, 
    36.84210526, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), Group_C = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Group_D = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), Group_E = c(76.19047619, -26.31578947, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 19.56521739, -34.69387755, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), Group_F = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Cluster = c("A28", 
    "A34", "A38", "A1", "A37", "A37", "A37", "A1", "A35", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), Cluster_location = c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 19L, 10L, 2L, 11L, 32L, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), Function = c("Biological processes", "Molecular functions", 
    "cellular components", "cellular components", "cellular components", 
    "cellular components", "Biological processes", "Biological processes", 
    "TBD", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), Aggregate = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "A8", "A8", "A8", "A8", "A8", 
    "A8", "A8", "A8", "A8"), sub_aggregate = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
    9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

> Expected Output

```
dput(df_2)
structure(list(position = c("A28.1", "A34.1", "A38.2", "A1.19", 
"A37.10", "A37.2", "A37.11", "A1.32", "A35.6", "A8.35", "A8.36", 
"A8.37", "A8.38", "A8.39", "A8.40", "A8.41", "A8.42", "A8.9"), 
    Set = c("M10.1", "M10.3", "M10.4", "M11.1", "M11.2", "M11.3", 
    "M11.4", "M12.1", "M12.10", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    ""), Group_A = c(95.23809524, -63.15789474, 33.33333333, 
    0, -23.33333333, -26.31578947, -20.83333333, 17.39130435, 
    -67.34693878, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Group_B = c(0, 
    36.84210526, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), Group_C = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Group_D = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), Group_E = c(76.19047619, -26.31578947, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 19.56521739, -34.69387755, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), Group_F = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Cluster = c("A28", 
    "A34", "A38", "A1", "A37", "A37", "A37", "A1", "A35", "A8", 
    "A8", "A8", "A8", "A8", "A8", "A8", "A8", "A8"), Cluster_location = c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 19L, 10L, 2L, 11L, 32L, 6L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
    40L, 41L, 42L, 9L), Function = c("Biological processes", 
    "Molecular functions", "cellular components", "cellular components", 
    "cellular components", "cellular components", "Biological processes", 
    "Biological processes", "TBD", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", ""), Aggregate = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), sub_aggregate = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

#################################

**Edited: After running the below suggested code.**

```
dput(df_n_v1)
structure(list(position = c("A28.1", "A34.1", "A38.2", "A1.19", 
"A37.10", "A37.2", "A37.11", "A1.32", "A35.6", "A8.35", "A8.36", 
"A8.37", "A8.38", "A8.39", "A8.40", "A8.41", "A8.42", "A8.9"), 
    Set = c("M10.1", "M10.3", "M10.4", "M11.1", "M11.2", "M11.3", 
    "M11.4", "M12.1", "M12.10", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    ""), Group_A = c(95.23809524, -63.15789474, 33.33333333, 
    0, -23.33333333, -26.31578947, -20.83333333, 17.39130435, 
    -67.34693878, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Group_B = c(0, 
    36.84210526, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), Group_C = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Group_D = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), Group_E = c(76.19047619, -26.31578947, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 19.56521739, -34.69387755, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), Group_F = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Cluster = c("A28NA", 
    "A34NA", "A38NA", "A1NA", "A37NA", "A37NA", "A37NA", "A1NA", 
    "A35NA", "NAA8", "NAA8", "NAA8", "NAA8", "NAA8", "NAA8", 
    "NAA8", "NAA8", "NAA8"), Cluster_location = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
    19L, 10L, 2L, 11L, 32L, 6L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
    41L, 42L, 9L), Function = c("Biological processes", "Molecular functions", 
    "cellular components", "cellular components", "cellular components", 
    "cellular components", "Biological processes", "Biological processes", 
    "TBD", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unite`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df_2 <- df_1 %>% 
  unite(Cluster, Cluster, Aggregate, sep = "") %>% 
  unite(Cluster_location, Cluster_location, sub_aggregate, sep="") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Cluster_location = stringr::str_replace_all(Cluster_location, 'NA,?', ''))  # remove NA string
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the solution. But NA's are added to the Cluster column in my dataframe as suffix and prefix. How to resolve this? Example of the dataframe re-edited above.

Comment: See my edit. with `library(stringr)` `dplyr::mutate(Cluster_location = stringr::str_replace_all(Cluster_location, 'NA,?', ''))  # remove NA string` the NA should be removed

Comment: thank you. I was getting NA's in "Cluster" column. Perhaps, adding a line to your code helped. Does this looks OK?

Comment: df_n <- df_1 %>% 
  unite(Cluster, Cluster, Aggregate, sep = "") %>% 
  unite(Cluster_location, Cluster_location, sub_aggregate, sep="") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Cluster_location = stringr::str_replace_all(Cluster_location, 'NA,?', '')) %>% # remove NA string
  dplyr::mutate(Cluster = stringr::str_replace_all(Cluster, 'NA,?', ''))  # remove NA string

Comment: This might be due to `NA` in the orginal dataset. In the example dataset df_1 there are no NA in `Cluster` column. In case of NA in your original dataset then your code is OK. Please see here how to vote for a accepted answer: <https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work>